# Format DateTime in C# to append to file name

Tags: c#, .net

I need to format current DateTime in this format **dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss** and don't know how to do it. I read on Internet and then write this code:

```
DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:u}", saveNow));
```

But this returns the date on this format:

```
2013-04-24 23:11:34Z
```

Can any help me? I need the first format to append to a file name I'm creating.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: +1: Side note: "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss" could be more convenient for file names as it allows default sorting by name to match soring by date.

Comment: Use `HH` (uppercase) to get the 24-hour time; `hh` will only yield 12-hour time, which may cause collisions (depending on file frequency) or at least be confusing in your alphabetized file list.